# UIImagePickerController sometimes doesn't open

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I am working with UIImagePickerController and I have one method to open it.

```
       let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
       imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
       imagePickerController.delegate = self
       self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am testing on real device (iPad). Sometimes when I try to open the image picker, I get the following error.

```
2020-10-20 12:34:44.477121-0500 App[4711:2089779] [lifecycle] [u 5D794CD2-8F05-477E-BE27-2F222AC015CF:m (null)] [com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker(1.0)] Connection to plugin interrupted while in use.
2020-10-20 12:34:44.489960-0500 App[4711:2089777] [lifecycle] [u 5D794CD2-8F05-477E-BE27-2F222AC015CF:m (null)] [com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker(1.0)] Connection to plugin invalidated while in use.
2020-10-20 12:34:44.490563-0500 App[4711:2089767] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
2020-10-20 12:34:44.490653-0500 App[4711:2089767] [Generic] -[PUPhotoPickerHostViewController viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:] Error Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
```

But when I remove the line

```
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

the image picker is always open.

Does someone know why I get this error?

Comment: Just remove it. It isn't your place to set the modal presentation style of a UIImagePickerController. It isn't your view controller to manipulate. Its modal presentation style is `.automatic` and it needs to stay that way.

Comment: yes I was thinking for remove but I want to know if someone has the same error and if exist another solution.

Comment: What would need a "solution"? Just present the picker the way it wants to be presented and don't try to mess with it.

Comment: thank you, I will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the recommendation the problem was fixed, removing this line, it's happen on ipad.

```
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```